# Can't save documents in library and folders with accents - SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-library, save

Since the update of IE11 to version 11.0.115 (KB4489873) we have a problem when creating document from SharePoint 2013.
The problem is linked to the use of characters with accents (é, è, à,…) in the folder (or document set) name.
For example:
I have a library with a folder called "Vive le vélo":

[image]

I create a document from within the library:

[image]

It opens up correct in Word. When I try to save I see this in the address bar:
[image]
Word is showing %E9 instead of é.

Ofcourse resulting in an error when trying to save:
[image]
The document name containes invalid characters.

So it seems that Internet Explorer does not send the encode url to the client?

When I open the library from within Word the address in the address bar it displayed correctly:

[image]
We tested with version IE 11.0.110 and there we do not have this problem. When we upgrade it to IE 11.0.115 the problem is the same.

Any ideas?
Solution here: [Can't open document in library with ''é'', ''à'' and other character with accent SharePoint 2016](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245015/cant-open-document-in-library-with-%C3%A9-%C3%A0-and-other-character-with-accent), does not help.

We're using SharePoint 2013 and Office 2016.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: can you add hotfix link. We have the same issue and I can´t find the hotfix that you are speak about. Please provide link to it.

Comment: I don't have info about a possible hotfix. The comment from Mike is not helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new update resolves the problem on my pc.
Was 11.0.115, now 11.0.120
[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4493435/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-april-12-2019

On Windows 10 - 1709

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes with a windows security update: KB4489899

Possible Solutions:

- Uninstall Update
- Use Edge, Chrome, …
- Set the following registry keys (maybe you have to adapt the key to your office version):

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Internet]
  "FSSHTTPOff"=dword:00000001
  "FSSHTTPSOff"=dword:00000001

Caution: The registry key will force office to access SharePoint via WebDAV instead of SOAP! Further information: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/using-the-fsshttpoff-registry-key-fd193fa2-9b23-4e60-8527-1bf760b2d470

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard! Uninstalling KB4489899 has in fact resolved the issue (IE now at 11.0.112 instead of 11.0.115) while we wait for the next KB4493435 to be available.

Answer (score 0):

[Delete your Office Document Cache](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-your-office-document-cache-b1d3765e-d71b-4bb8-99ca-acd22c42995d)

Comment: Problem stays the same.

Comment: Sorry, it helped me.

Answer (score -1):

We got a new uppdate (hotfix) from MS to fix this problem!

Comment: Hi Mike, can you add hotfix link, for other users reference?